# Help with jQuery element selection

Tags: jquery

I have a list of links as follows:

```
<li>
    <a onclick="add_to_shortlist('225')" href="javascript:void(0);" id="link_225">
    <img src="images/icon-add.png">Add</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a onclick="add_to_shortlist('226')" href="javascript:void(0);" id="link_226">
    <img src="images/icon-add.png">Add</a>
</li>
```

I'd like to change the text "Add" to "Remove" - and the image src from "images/icon-add.png" to "images/icon-remove.png"

How can I do this?

I know I can select the link clicked using:

```
    $('#link_' + song_id)
```

and use this to change the image

```
    $(".img").attr("src").replace("images/icon-add.png", "images/icon-remove.png");
```

But am unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have any event handlers on the image itself, you can do this:

```
$('#link_' + song_id).html(
    '<img src="images/icon-remove.png">Remove</a>'
);
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/erefi5)

That *replaces* the content of the link with the updated `img` tag and text. The reason I mentioned not having event handlers on the image is that since this *replaces* the `img` element, any handlers on the old element are not assigned to the new element.

If you need to preserve the old image and just change its `src`, you can use [`detach`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/):

```
var link = $('#link_' + song_id),
    img  = link.find('img');
img.detach();
img.attr("src", "images/icon-remove.png");
link.html("Remove");
link.prepend(img);
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/erefi5/2)

`detach` takes an element out of the DOM but *without* removing any event handlers. Then we change the `src`, update the text in the link, and re-insert the same `img` element rather than replacing it.

---

Rather than using `onclick=` to assign an event handler and changing the handler when you change what it means, I'd use modern ways of assigning the handler and then have the handler figure out what needs to be done. Something like this:

HTML:

```
<a id="link_255"><img src="images/icon-add.png">Add</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $('a[id^=link]').click(function(event) {
    var link = $(this),
        song_id = this.id.substring(5); // Drop the "link_" part

    if (link.text() == "Add") {
      add_to_shortlist(song_id, link);
    }
    else {
      remove_from_shortlist(song_id, link);
    }
    return false; // Prevent the link from being followed
  });

});

function add_to_shortlist(song_id, link) {
  if (!link) {
    link = $('#link_' + song_id);
  }

  // ...add the song...

  // Update link
  link.html('<img src="images/icon-remove.png">Remove');
}

function remove_from_shortlist(song_id, link) {
  if (!link) {
    link = $('#link_' + song_id);
  }

  // ...remove the song...

  // Update link
  link.html('<img src="images/icon-add.png">Add');
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/erefi5/3)

Note that I've added a second argument to `add_to_shortlist` and `remove_from_shortlist`, but I've made it optional. That's because we can avoid looking up the link if we already have it, but if you're calling this from another part of your code that won't provide the second argument, we'd want to look it up. The above replaces the `img` element, but it's easy enough to swap in the code from example #2 in the main answer to preserve the `img` element if you need to.

Comment: Great this works but I also need to change the onclick="add_to_shortlist('226')" to become onclick="remove_from_shortlist('226')"

Comment: @Simon: I'd recommend handling that (and in fact the whole way you're hooking it up), let me post an addendum.